# How to continuously try something in powershell until it succeeds?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Using the basic construct:

```
try
{
    Do-Something
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Something threw an exception"
}
```

Is it possible to keep trying the Do-Something until it succeeds? Perhaps using a while loopp like this:

```
$Timeout = 60
$timer = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
$t = 0
while (($timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $Timeout) -and ($t -ne 1))) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    try
    {
        Do-Something
        $t = 1
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Output "Something threw an exception"
    }
}
$timer.Stop()
```

Here I use a timer to make sure PowerShell doesn't run indefinitely.
It should keep trying until the `try` succeeds and `$t = 1` is executed. However, it fails in about 2 seconds. Please help.

More specifically the Do-Something is:

```
(Get-Process -Name FineReader).MainWindowHandle
```

I'd like the code to keep trying until `FineReader` exists and it can get the `MainWindowHandle`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `$t`? It exits immediately because your conditional fails, you need the timer to be less than 60 **and** `$t` to not equal `1`, but on the first iteration you set `$t` to be `1`, so the loop exits.

Comment: @arco444 I thought the loop would fail when the `Do-Something` fails and it would not get to execute the `$t = 1` until the `Do-Something` succeeded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `break` keyword.

```
# Set the erroracton preference to stop when an error occurs,
$ErrorActionPreferenceBak = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference    = 'Stop'

While($True){
    try{
        Do-Something
        break
    }
    catch{
        Write-Output "Something failed"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 # wait for a seconds before next attempt.
    }
    finally{
        #Reset the erroracton preference
        $ErrorActionPreference = $ErrorActionPreferenceBak
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion worked with my added clarification (see question) as well!

Comment: The only thing I did is change the first line to:
`$ErrorActionPreferenceBak = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Your `Do-Something` should be called with the switch `-ErrorAction Stop` in order to issue a terminating exception that can be caught by `try`

For that, you also need to bind your function as a CmdLet. For example:

```
function DoSomething {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    Param(
    )

    # Your code

}
```

And then call your function with the `-ErrorAction Stop` switch:

```
try {
    Do-Something -ErrorAction Stop
}
```

If your `DoSomething` is not a function but rather an existing powershell CmdLet, then ... you guessed it, just call it with `-ErrorAction Stop`

You can learn more about the try/catch/finally in powershell [here](https://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell)

Comment: `-ErrorAction Stop` is available for cmdlets, If `Do-SomeThing` is a function, Error handling capabilities has to be explicitly done.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a function failing in 9 out of 10 calls:

```
function Get-RandomFail{
    $value = [Random]::new().Next(10);
    if ($value -ne 5) { throw }
    return $value
}
```

And you want to limit time window, you can use following:

```
function Try-Invoke{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        $Action,
        $MaxSeconds,
        $Delay=1
    )
    $timeout = [timespan]::FromSeconds($MaxSeconds)
    $start = [DateTime]::Now
    do {
        try {
            return &$Action
        } catch {
            Write-Verbose "Error"
        }
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $Delay
    } until (([DateTime]::Now - $start) -gt $timeout)
    throw
}

$result = Try-Invoke {Get-RandomFail} -MaxSeconds 5 -Verbose
```

`Get-RandomFail` will be invoked until no error occurs or until time is over. You can also use `Delay` argument to modify sleep time after every unsuccesfull `Get-RandomFail` invocation.